# How can I build a makefile project with Xcode 5?

Tags: c++, xcode

I would like to use Xcode to debug a C++ program step by step. The project can be build using make. How can I build it using Xcode 5?

Comment: Did you follow the steps for ["Building Makefile Projects With Xcode"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Porting/Conceptual/PortingUnix/preparing/preparing.html) ? I've not done it since 4.6, but I can't imagine it would have changed much.

Answer (score 12):

Here are the steps

1) create a new project using the following
     a) go to OS X other
     b) Create an empty project

2) create a blank file (under OS X other again) and call it Makefile

3) create a new target (file -> new -> target - call it whatever you want)
       go to OS X target and select external build system

4) If you want a particular PATH variable you can Add a new user define setting (under
editor -> add Build Setting -> Add user defined setting

5) This should enable your target to be the makefile