# Automating compilation and tests in XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, bash

I'm attempting to set up XCode so that it will execute my C++ program several times, modifying two different macros on each iteration. A bash script that would accomplish the same thing would be something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
# execute the program for varying numbers of array sizes and local work sizes
for arr_size in 1000 10000 100000 1000000 2000000 40000000 6000000 8000000
do
echo NUM_ELEMENTS = $arr_size

for local in 8 16 32 64 128 256 512
do
echo LOCAL_SIZE = $subdiv
g++ -D NUM_ELEMENTS=$arr_size -D LOCAL_SIZE=$local project06.cpp -o project06 -lm -fopenmp
./project06 >> 'array_mult'$arr_size'.txt' #create a separate file for each NUM_ELEMENTS.
done
echo
done
```

I've tried adding a run script phase to the build phases, but that's not quite what I want -- essentially I need to build the project multiple times, each time changing macros and outputting the program results to a varying file.

I know how to do this w/ regular scripting via terminal, but I'm trying to find out how to do this via XCode.

Thanks!

Comment: [foreach](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Foreach-Function.html) function in makefile will help. To use makefile in XCode, please refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21617017/how-can-i-build-a-makefile-project-with-xcode-5). By the way, why not consider to pass `NUM_ELEMENTS` to the command line argument of your program?

Comment: @where23 i'm basing my script off a template piece of code that i have. since the code uses preprocessor macros to define NUM_ELEMENTS and LOCAL_SIZE, i'm trying to make minimal changes to the original code, if possible.