# Incorporate a Makefile in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, makefile

I have a Makefile set up, is there any way to "port" its settings to Xcode so all of my settings there will be applied to Xcode's build settings and dependencies?

I've tried looking it up online but i'm using Xcode 7.3.1 while all of what i've found was referring to older versions so i couldn't really find the matching settings.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I build a makefile project with Xcode 5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21617017/how-can-i-build-a-makefile-project-with-xcode-5)

Comment: It didn't have the fill answer but it helped, thanks! Now after the build succeeded, where does xcode 7 build to? i tried looking into:
/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData but i couldn't find that file